New samba install on 24.04 won't start
I'm trying to apt install samba on a recent install of 24.04 server.
No problems are reported but the service doesn't (and won't) start. There is no meaningful info in the status report or the systemd error log :
○ smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exec-condition) since Mon 2024-09-16 12:41:40 NZST; 4s ago
  Condition: start condition unmet at Mon 2024-09-16 12:41:40 NZST; 4s ago
       Docs: man:smbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
    Process: 8213 ExecCondition=/usr/share/samba/is-configured smb (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 1ms
Sep 16 12:41:40 orion systemd[1]: Starting smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon...
Sep 16 12:41:40 orion systemd[1]: smbd.service: Skipped due to 'exec-condition'.
Sep 16 12:41:40 orion systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon being skipped.

Oddly the installation (although it showed no error) hasn't created a smb.conf, or a /etc/samba directory. Also there is no var/log/samba. Does the first-run of the service sets these up? Seems a bit odd the installation didn't at least create the basic /etc config?
I've uninstalled, rebooted and reinstalled several times with identical results.
The lack of any specific leads in the log (presumably because of a very early failure of the service) leaves me baffled - I really have no idea where to start looking on this one.
Has anyone any experience of this / suggestions of how to diagnose it?

I'm pretty sure when I installed samba it started the service automatically after being installed. /etc/samba/smb.conf isn't listed in the files that the install creates so maybe it does get created at first run.
